# gstreamer functionality in Python?

Tags: python, pip, gstreamer

I have a python script I want to run that uses gstreamer.  the first line in my code is "import gst"...and this creates an error...when I attempt to "pip install gst" within that directory I see the following message:

"Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement gst (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for gst"

I have updated pip, I have installed the current version of Python (still also have version 2.7 installed)...what am I doing wrong here?  How can I utilize gstreamer functionality within Python?

Any help greatly appreciated, I thank you in advance.